# (C++) Container of templated classes

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I'm sure this question comes up a lot, but my question has a slight difference which I haven't seen addressed (perhaps this is due to poor design on my part: I'm pretty new to C++).

For example, let's say I have a base class as such:

```
class Var {
public:
    Var(std::string id, std::string description) : _id(id), _description(description) {}
private:
    std::string _id, _description;
public:
    std::string id() {
        return this->_id;
    }

    std::string description() {
        this->_description;
    }
};
```

And some implementations like this:

```
template<
    typename N,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<N>::value, N>::type
>
class VarNumber : public Var {
public:
    VarNumber(std::string id, std::string desc, N value, N min, N max) : Var(id, desc), _value(value), _min(min), _max(max) {}
    VarNumber(std::string id, N value, N min, N max) : VarNumber(id, "", value, min, max) {}
private:
    N _value;
    N _min, _max;
public:
    N value() {
        return this->_value;
    }

    void set(N value) {
        this->_value = std::clamp(value, this->_min, this->_max);
    }

    N min_value() {
        return this->_min;
    }

    N max_value() {
        return this->_max;
    }
};
```

```
class VarBool : public Var {
public:
    VarBool(std::string id, std::string desc, bool value) : Var(id, desc), _value(value) {}
    VarBool(std::string id, bool value) : VarBool(id, "", value) {}
private:
    bool _value;
public:
    bool value() {
        return this->_value;
    }

    bool set_value(bool value) {
        this->_value = value;
    }

    bool toggle() {
        this->set_value(!this->_value);
    }
};
```

Say I wanted a container to hold all implementations of Var in one place. Now, I've been told that abusing inheritance to do this is not the way to go, i.e.:

```
std::vector<Var*> vars;
vars.push_back(new VarBool(...));
vars.push_back(new VarNumber<float>(...));
```

Especially since the above would require a cast to access methods specific to each `Var` implementation:

```
(static_cast<VarBool*>(vars.at(0)))->toggle();
float max = (static_cast<VarNumber<float>*>(vars.at(1)))->max_value());
```

I've also tried defining the container like:

```
std::vector<std::variant<VarBool, VarNumber<int>, VarNumber<float>, ... >>
```

This would work if there was a finite number of types to be templated for each Var implementation, but that doesn't work for my purposes. I have other `Var` types that are templated for enums, that cannot be defined at compile time:

```
template<
    typename E,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<E>::value>::type
>
class VarMOption : public Var {
...
};
```

What's the best way to go about this? I've tried implementing a type erasure pattern but that only works if each "child" has the same methods.

**I'd like to design this in a way that while storing all types in a single container, there are no pointless states represented, i.e. a `max_value()` method on a `VarBool`, or a `toggle()` method on a `VarNumber<float>`.**

Is this a result of poor design? What's the best approach for this?

Thanks.

**EDIT: Example regarding @ALX23z's comment**

```
enum Target {
    FOO,
    BAR,
    QAZ
}

std::unique_ptr<Var> enum_var = std::make_unique(Var("test enum", "description"));
enum_var->variant = EnumVar<Target>(Target::FOO); //EnumVar doesn't exist, since we would have to somehow define it in the variant

// But this would work:
std::unique_ptr<Var> num_var = std::make_unique(Var("test num", "desc"));
num_var->variant = NumberVar<float>(3.f, 0.f, 10.f);

// In Var class:
class Var {
// constructor here... (2 strs)

std::variant<NumberVar<float>, NumberVar<int> .. etc> variant;
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Here's what I came up with. It's very ugly.

```
class VarBool {
public:
    VarBool(bool value_) : value_(value_) {}
private:
    bool value_;
public:
    bool& value() {
        return this->value_;
    }

    void set(const bool& other) {
        this->value_ = other;
    }
};

template<
    typename N,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<N>::value, N>::type
>
class VarNumber {
public:
    VarNumber(N value_, N min_, N max_) : value_(value_), min_(min_), max_(max_) {}
private:
    N value_, min_, max_;
public:
    N& value() {
        return this->value_;
    }

    void set(const N& other) {
        this->value_ = std::clamp(other, this->min_, this->max_);
    }

    N minimum() {
        return this->min_;
    }

    N maximum() {
        return this->max_;
    }
};

class VarWrapper {
    using V = std::variant<VarBool, VarNumber<int>, VarNumber<float>>;
public:
    VarWrapper(std::string id_, std::string desc_, V inner_) : id_(id_), desc_(desc_), inner_(inner_) {}
    VarWrapper(std::string id_, V inner_) : VarWrapper(id_, "", inner_) {}
private:
    std::string id_, desc_;
    V inner_;
public:
    std::string id() {
        return this->id_;
    }

    std::string desc() {
        return this->desc_;
    }

    template<typename T>
    T& unwrap() {
        if (std::holds_alternative<T>(this->inner_))
            return std::get<T>(this->inner_);
    }

};
```

Usage:

```
std::shared_ptr<VarWrapper> w_var = std::make_shared<VarWrapper>(VarWrapper("name", "description", VarNumber<float>(1.5f, 0.f, 10.f)));
float& unwrapped_var_val = w_var->unwrap<VarNumber<float>>().value();
std::cout << unwrapped_var_val << "\n"; //prints 1.5f
w_var->unwrap<VarNumber<float>>().set(200.f);
std::cout << unwrapped_var_val << "\n"; //prints 10.f (clamped)
```

Comment: `std::vector<Var*>` is a good way to do it (`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Var>>` would probably be better). If you know that `vars.at(0)` will always be a `VarBool` and `vars.at(1)` will always be a `VarNumber<float>`, you probably want a struct with 2 members. If not, you have to check with `dynamic_cast` anyways

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll have to check with `dynamic_cast`, since the positioning of the `Var`s in the vector is uncertain.

Comment: This isn't addressed because the classes are poorly designed.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I suspected. I'm open to any design suggestions.

Comment: You have two strings in the base class, why not just add another string or two for the extra values? And just convert when needed? You already restrict yourself to non-computation classes by having strings then why make it overly complicated with templates and inheritance? There is the principle KISS. Follow it.

Comment: I think you need to have a single class that contains the two strings and a variant that covers all types you need - something like `variant< array<int,3>, array<double,3>, bool>` or instead of array use custom classes for better expressiveness. This way you have a single class `Var` and just make `std::vector<Var>`. This will save you unnecessary allocations, dynamic_casts, dereferences, bugs, etc.

Comment: @ALX23z What would you do about a class that needs to be templated with an enum?

Comment: @marcyeo enum? Depends on how many enums you have. If one then just add to the variant. Otherwise, I'd just use a string instead of enum - then just try-convert for various usages. Technically, one can store enum value inside an integer - but go figure what type of enum that is.

Comment: @ALX23z I'll post an example in the main post.

Comment: One tiny thing is that it is considered [bad practice to start your variables with underscor](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/191833/292822)

Comment: @marcyeo you should be able to use `enum class` inside the variant - check it out in the c++ reference. Infact it is generally better to use `enum class` instead of `enum` in most cases. If you have many enums then just add a `std::string` to the variant to represent all of them: `var.variant = "Target::FOO"` - just add function that converts these enums to strings and backwards for easy and reliable use (sadly it cannot be automated... no reflection).

Comment: You seem to have conflicting design goals: don't have things which don't apply for all types in the interface, and also easily use type-specific features from the interface. No matter what technical tricks you use, you'll have to balance those somehow.

Comment: Ideally, I'd have a type-agnostic interface, with a parentheses operator to "unwrap" it, which would reveal the underlying type with all type-specific features there.

Comment: @ALX23z I edited the original post with the solution I came up with. I really don't like it.

Comment: @marcyeo there is no such thing in C++. What you can do, is use function `visit` designed to deal with variants https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit and checkout their example of use.

Comment: @ALX23z Did you see the edit in my post? I didn’t mean to “unwrap” in place. Just to reveal access to the inner Var. I’ll take a closer look at the visitor pattern.

Comment: @marcyeo yeah, saw it. That's what I refered by "there is no such thing in C++" the syntax simply does not allow it. You gotta use `visit` instead.

Comment: @ALX23z Could you clarify how you'd use the visitor pattern in this context? Having a bit of trouble.

Comment: @marcyeo instead of getting value you send lambda/class that perform the action you want. Check the cppreference - there are examples in the link.